# How to extract grayscale image from a video with ffmpeg-library?

Tags: c, video, ffmpeg, libav

I'v compiled and tested this [tutorial](http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial01.c) from [here](http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial01.html) which works just fine. After I tried to edit the tutorial to read/convert frames into [grayscale](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.7/pixfmt_8h.html#ace4d36d981b86af5f0dc2d6429701684). I just changed `pFrameRGB` to `pFrameGray`, `PIX_FMT_RGB24` to `PIX_FMT_GRAY16` and to save just the 200th frame. It compiles and run but the image don't show the expected. What's wrong?

The image:
[image]

The edited code:

```
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>

#include <stdio.h>

// compatibility with newer API
#if LIBAVCODEC_VERSION_INT < AV_VERSION_INT(55,28,1)
#define av_frame_alloc avcodec_alloc_frame
#define av_frame_free avcodec_free_frame
#endif

void SaveFrame(AVFrame *pFrame, int width, int height, int iFrame) {
  FILE *pFile;
  char szFilename[32];
  int  y;

  // Open file
  sprintf(szFilename, "frame%d.ppm", iFrame);
  pFile=fopen(szFilename, "wb");
  if(pFile==NULL)
    return;

  // Write header
  fprintf(pFile, "P6\n%d %d\n255\n", width, height);

  // Write pixel data
  for(y=0; y<height; y++)
    fwrite(pFrame->data[0]+y*pFrame->linesize[0], 1, width*3, pFile);

  // Close file
  fclose(pFile);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  // Initalizing these to NULL prevents segfaults!
  AVFormatContext   *pFormatCtx = NULL;
  int               i, videoStream;
  AVCodecContext    *pCodecCtxOrig = NULL;
  AVCodecContext    *pCodecCtx = NULL;
  AVCodec           *pCodec = NULL;
  AVFrame           *pFrame = NULL;
  AVFrame           *pFrameGRAY = NULL;
  AVPacket          packet;
  int               frameFinished;
  int               numBytes;
  uint8_t           *buffer = NULL;
  struct SwsContext *sws_ctx = NULL;

  if(argc < 2) {
    printf("Please provide a movie file\n");
    return -1;
  }
  // Register all formats and codecs
  av_register_all();

  // Open video file
  if(avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, argv[1], NULL, NULL)!=0)
    return -1; // Couldn't open file

  // Retrieve stream information
  if(avformat_find_stream_info(pFormatCtx, NULL)<0)
    return -1; // Couldn't find stream information

  // Dump information about file onto standard error
  av_dump_format(pFormatCtx, 0, argv[1], 0);

  // Find the first video stream
  videoStream=-1;
  for(i=0; i<pFormatCtx->nb_streams; i++)
    if(pFormatCtx->streams[i]->codec->codec_type==AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
      videoStream=i;
      break;
    }
  if(videoStream==-1)
    return -1; // Didn't find a video stream

  // Get a pointer to the codec context for the video stream
  pCodecCtxOrig=pFormatCtx->streams[videoStream]->codec;
  // Find the decoder for the video stream
  pCodec=avcodec_find_decoder(pCodecCtxOrig->codec_id);
  if(pCodec==NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Unsupported codec!\n");
    return -1; // Codec not found
  }
  // Copy context
  pCodecCtx = avcodec_alloc_context3(pCodec);
  if(avcodec_copy_context(pCodecCtx, pCodecCtxOrig) != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't copy codec context");
    return -1; // Error copying codec context
  }

  // Open codec
  if(avcodec_open2(pCodecCtx, pCodec, NULL)<0)
    return -1; // Could not open codec

  // Allocate video frame
  pFrame=av_frame_alloc();

  // Allocate an AVFrame structure
  pFrameGRAY=av_frame_alloc();
  if(pFrameGRAY==NULL)
    return -1;

  // Determine required buffer size and allocate buffer
  numBytes=avpicture_get_size(PIX_FMT_GRAY16, pCodecCtx->width,
                  pCodecCtx->height);
  buffer=(uint8_t *)av_malloc(numBytes*sizeof(uint8_t));

  // Assign appropriate parts of buffer to image planes in pFrameGRAY
  // Note that pFrameGRAY is an AVFrame, but AVFrame is a superset
  // of AVPicture
  avpicture_fill((AVPicture *)pFrameGRAY, buffer, PIX_FMT_GRAY16,
         pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height);

  // initialize SWS context for software scaling
  sws_ctx = sws_getContext(pCodecCtx->width,
               pCodecCtx->height,
               pCodecCtx->pix_fmt,
               pCodecCtx->width,
               pCodecCtx->height,
               PIX_FMT_GRAY16,
               SWS_BILINEAR,
               NULL,
               NULL,
               NULL
               );

  // Read frames and save first five frames to disk
  i=0;
  while(av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, &packet)>=0) {
    // Is this a packet from the video stream?
    if(packet.stream_index==videoStream) {
      // Decode video frame
      avcodec_decode_video2(pCodecCtx, pFrame, &frameFinished, &packet);

      // Did we get a video frame?
      if(frameFinished) {
    // Convert the image from its native format to GRAY
    sws_scale(sws_ctx, (uint8_t const * const *)pFrame->data,
          pFrame->linesize, 0, pCodecCtx->height,
          pFrameGRAY->data, pFrameGRAY->linesize);

    // Save the frame to disk
    if(++i==200)
      SaveFrame(pFrameGRAY, pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height, 
            i);
      }
    }

    // Free the packet that was allocated by av_read_frame
    av_free_packet(&packet);
  }

  // Free the GRAY image
  av_free(buffer);
  av_frame_free(&pFrameGRAY);

  // Free the YUV frame
  av_frame_free(&pFrame);

  // Close the codecs
  avcodec_close(pCodecCtx);
  avcodec_close(pCodecCtxOrig);

  // Close the video file
  avformat_close_input(&pFormatCtx);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Updated my question and added an image. The image is distorted. The left part is added to the right, but the dimensions are still correct. Neither it's grayscale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem is here:

```
fprintf(pFile, "P6\n%d %d\n255\n", width, height);
```

According to some info on PPM i found: http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/ppm/ you're writing the PPM header with the identifier `P6` which means "rgb color". If you're making a greyscale image, you want to use `P5` instead.

As well, you're using the pixel format `PIX_FMT_GRAY16` from ffmpeg, but you're interpreting it as bytes. you probably meant to use `PIX_FMT_GRAY8` instead. If you actually want 16-bit grayscale in your output, you should change the third number in the PPM header from 255 to 65535.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited like you wrote but now the inner part of the image is zoomed into the picture. Other image parts are cropped.

Comment: @user1587451 just change `3 * width` to `width` in `fwrite` in `SaveFrame` function. It's just so to understand why is it necessary.